# Toshiba Laptop keyboard and mouse intermittently stop working

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad, toshiba-satellite

Hey I've done quite a bit of googling and can't find the solution to my problem.

I've also been away from Linux for over a year so if I need to provide my information I apologize.

However I've installed Ubuntu 12.04 64bit and on my Toshiba L875D-S7332 laptop when it boots up sometimes the onboard touchpad and keyboard don't work.  I'm able to use an external usb keyboard and mouse and sometimes going into Settings > Lanuage Support and switching the Keyboard input method from ibus and back fixes it.  But not always.  And sometimes they randomly start working.

I'm sure it's probably a simple fix but since its randomly resolving itself at times I can't pinpoint what the cause or resolution is.

Answer (score 0):

This used to work for 13.04 and early 13.10:

edit the following line in /etc/default/grub:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="nosplash i8042.reset=1 i8042.nomux=1

save and reboot. After upgrading to the most recent packages though, my touchpad has quit working.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem with my Toshiba laptop.
I had already created this file to properly unload/reload psmouse module while hibernating

file: /etc/pm/sleep.d/27-psmouse

```
    case $1 in
    hibernate)
        rmmod psmouse
        ;;
    suspend)
        rmmod psmouse
        ;;
    thaw)
    modprobe psmouse
        ;;
    resume)
    modprobe psmouse
        ;;
    *)
        echo Something is not right.
        ;;
esac
```

But that didn't worked

So I just added following line to top of my /etc/acpi/powerbtn.sh

```
echo -n 'serio0' >  /sys/bus/serio/drivers/atkbd/unbind
rmmod psmouse; sleep 1; modprobe psmouse;
```

Now if laptop keyboard and mouse is not working, I just presses the power button. 
Then, keyboard will become ready at that instant, and touch-pad will become ready after 1 second.